# Adding a different image as a button to each LI using css and text on html

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Im trying to make it to were I can add an image to each LI not a bullet image but an image to represent the button itself, and I want to be able to use text in the html.
I have tried #glass_menu ul li.shard1,.shard1 I cant figure it out can someone please help!!

css:

```
#glass_menu {
width:984px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
position:relative;
bottom:-20px;
}
#glass_menu ul li{
padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
display: inline;
}

.shard1{
background-image:url(glasshard1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:30px;
height:30px;

}
.shard2{
background-image:url(glasshard2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:30px;
height:30px;    
}
.shard3{

}
.shard4{

}
.shard5{ 

}
.shard6{

}
```

html:

```
<div id="glass_menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="shard1"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
<li class="shard2"><a href="Estimate.php"><span>Estimate</span></a></li>
<li class="shard3"><a href="why-should-you-choose-us.html"><span>help</span></a></li>
<li class="shard4"><a href="Contact.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li class="shard5"><a href="affiliates.html"><span>Affiliates</span></a></li>
<li class="shard6"><a href="Location.html"><span>Location</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--end glass_menu div-->
```

Comment: Is this background-image not working ? I think its working as [I see here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbxhj/1/). and if you want to remove bullets then use `list-style: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Reset your list:

```
#glass_menu ul li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

2) Don't style the LI, except for positioning/floats.

```
#glass_menu li {
    float:left
}
```

3) Style the LINK and use `display:block`. Remove the SPAN, there's no reason for it to be there.

```
.shard1 a {
    background-image:url(glasshard1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    display:block;
    padding-left: 30px; <--- you need this to move your text to the right to uncover the background image.
}
```

4) Read my tutorial: [I love lists.](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/)

Comment: works for me. ks for the tut ive been trying to figure out the classes and divs for all the li,ul,menu and stuff